# Delete localdb in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, localdb

I am writing some UnitTests with NUnit and Entity Framework.
How to delete the whole localdb database from Entity Framework level?

**Note:** I don't want to clear the tables' data. I want to delete the whole database.

Also I am able to create a localdb file in my application working directory provided the database had not been created:

```cs
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "");
var testDbFileName = String.Format(@"UnitTestDB.mdf");
var testDbFileNameWithPath = path + @"\" + testDbFileName;

var connectionString =
String.Format(
    @"Data Source=(localdb)\V11.0;Initial Catalog={0};Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename={1};MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
    "UnitTestDB", testDbFileNameWithPath);

//Here would be the code passing connection string to DbContext and so on..
```

Deleting only the file "UnitTestDB.mdf" is not enough. There is still a reference to the db in SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this in code.  Stick to EF code first if you can :-)

1) EF has a nice option on the context.

```
 Context.Database.Delete()
```

2) if you want old school SQLCommand/SqlConnection approach something like this hack routine...

```
 public  bool DropDB(string DBName, string ConnectionString)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        string stmt = null;

        int rowCount = 0;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DBName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(DBName, "DBName required");

        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

           stmt = "DROP DATABASE " + DBName ;

            cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, conn);
            conn.Open();
            rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //todo  whatever
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null) conn.Dispose();
            if (cmd != null) conn.Dispose();
        }
        if (rowCount == -1) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful answer. Before I read it I had been creating a new db in a TestFixture by generating a new Guid so the db (and its structure) had been being recreated each time. Then I was deleting all the databases from SQL Management Studio level.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a shell command to delete it.
If you want, you can add your credentials with `-U Username` `-P Password` parameters.

Check out [sqlcmd documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)!

```
sqlcmd -e -S "(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -d "master" -Q "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'your-database-name'; USE [master]; DROP DATABASE [your-database-name];"
```